# How to write COALESCE SQL creating multiple columns where rows need to be the same type

Tags: multiple-columns, coalesce

SQL Newbie here. I have tried to make sense of others posts, but I cannot seem to make this work.  I apologize in advance for incorrect terminology. I am here to learn from the wisdom of others.

I have a part number that has 3 different 'states'. Each part number has the same core characterset, but has a different prefix for the other two states.

1. Packaged product = 2-181032
2. Non-Packaged Product = R-181032
3. Part number in production = MF-R-181032

I want to be able to place each of the records above into one row, but three columns and such for the remaining part numbers. R- and MF- are only used as the prefixes stated above.  Here is what I have, but it does not filter the data into the columns as I like. Filter, meaning take the non-MF and non MF-R records and putting them into their own columns, and removing from the first column. I have removed the 3rd part number from the code because it I get a error of "GDS Exception. 335544800. Too many Contexts of Relation/Procedure/Views. Maximum allowed is 255"

```
SELECT part.num AS part, 
part.description AS description, 
uom.code AS uomcode,

COALESCE((SELECT SUM(qtyonhand.qty)                 
    FROM qtyonhand
    WHERE qtyonhand.partid = part.id
        AND part.num NOT LIKE '[MR]%'                  
        AND qtyonhand.locationgroupid IN ('1')),0) AS Qty,

COALESCE((SELECT SUM(qtynotavailable.qty)                 
    FROM qtynotavailable                
    WHERE qtynotavailable.partid = part.id
    AND part.num NOT LIKE '[MR]%'                   
    AND qtynotavailable.locationgroupid IN ('1')), 0) AS Unavailable,

COALESCE((SELECT SUM(qtycommitted.qty)                 
    FROM qtycommitted                
    WHERE qtycommitted.partid = part.id
        AND part.num NOT LIKE '[MR]%'                  
        AND qtycommitted.locationgroupid IN ('1')), 0) AS QtyCommitted, 

COALESCE((SELECT SUM(QtyAllocated.qty)                 
    FROM QtyAllocated                
    WHERE QtyAllocated.partID = Part.id
        AND part.num NOT LIKE '[MR]%'                   
        AND QtyAllocated.locationgroupid IN ('1')), 0) AS Allocated,

COALESCE((SELECT SUM(qtyonorder.qty)                 
    FROM qtyonorder                
    WHERE qtyonorder.partid = part.id
        AND part.num NOT LIKE '[MR]%'                   
        AND qtyonorder.locationgroupid IN ('1')), 0) AS OnOrder,


part.num AS part2,      
COALESCE((SELECT SUM(qtyonhand.qty)                 
    FROM qtyonhand
    WHERE qtyonhand.partid = part.id 
        AND part.num LIKE 'R-%'                 
        AND qtyonhand.locationgroupid IN ('1')),0) AS Qty2,

COALESCE((SELECT SUM(qtynotavailable.qty)                 
    FROM qtynotavailable                
    WHERE qtynotavailable.partid = part.id
    AND part.num LIKE 'R-%'                  
    AND qtynotavailable.locationgroupid IN ('1')), 0) AS Unavailable2,  

COALESCE((SELECT SUM(qtycommitted.qty)                 
    FROM qtycommitted                
    WHERE qtycommitted.partid = part.id
        AND part.num LIKE 'R-%'                 
        AND qtycommitted.locationgroupid IN ('1')), 0) AS QtyCommitted2,

COALESCE((SELECT SUM(QtyAllocated.qty)                 
    FROM QtyAllocated                
    WHERE QtyAllocated.partID = Part.id
        AND part.num LIKE 'R-%'                  
        AND QtyAllocated.locationgroupid IN ('1')), 0) AS Allocated2,

COALESCE((SELECT SUM(qtyonorder.qty)                 
    FROM qtyonorder                
    WHERE qtyonorder.partid = part.id
        AND part.num LIKE 'R-%'                  
        AND qtyonorder.locationgroupid IN ('1')), 0) AS OnOrder2

FROM part     
    LEFT JOIN uom ON part.uomid = uom.id  
WHERE part.num LIKE '%'   
    AND part.id != 0   
    AND part.typeid = 10   
    AND part.activeflag = 1  

ORDER BY part.num
```

Desired result is: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zr6GF.jpg)

Comment: Do you really keep e.g. quantity on hand and quantity committed in separate tables, or are these views? If so, it looks like it might be better (simpler, faster, clearer) to draw directly from the underlying table.

Comment: Thank you for your question. These are indeed views. however, i am not sure how to execute the code that would be required to pull the records as needed.